Determine p-value for sensitivity between two algorithms using R
In R, I have a dataframe that looks like this (2000+ rows):
Sample  AlgoA   AlgoB
A   FP  TP
B   TN  TN
C   TP  TP
D   FN  TP
E   FP  FP
F   TN  TN
G   TP  TP

The TN/TP etc is coming by comparing the algo to a truth set.
I've generated spec/sense values by doing the usual calculations, and also generated my 95% CIs.
I just need to now see if there's a statistical difference between the two groups. what should I do in this case? AlgoA and AlgoB are totally unrelated, just two different lab methods.
Using the sensitivity calculations (TP / (TP+FN)), I know AlgoB has better sensitivity. I want to know if this is 'significantly' better sensitivity, or not.

If you want advice on what statistical test to use for your data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. That's the site for statistical questions.


What do you mean by "statistical" difference? 2. How is it possible that for the "truth set" for sample A that one algorithm could have a false positive (FP) and the other have a true positive (TP)??


Ah the data was made up to easily share. There are no TP/FP combos similarly no FN/TN combos. Statistical difference meaning - I know already AlgoB performs better based off of sensitivity testing (TP / (TP+FN)). I want to know if AlgoB is significantly better or not.

Check out the confusion matrix here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix It is confusing, but if the actual condition is positive, then you either have TP or FN, and if the actual condition is negative, then you either have TN or FP.

You can make tables like
Actual negative cases
              AlgoB
                 correct false
AlgoA    correct 300     50
         false   150     500

Actual positive cases
              AlgoB
                 correct false
AlgoA    correct 250     150
         false   250     350

(I am just making up some numbers)
and test your assumptions about "AlgoA and AlgoB are totally unrelated" as well as test whether the probabilities for false/correct are the same. E.g., you could fit a binomial regression, or perform a G test or chi-squared test (see also Most appropriate statistical test for count data (2x2 contingency)).

Trajman & Luiz (2008) advocate for the use of a McNemar test from controls to compare specificities.
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

P <- c("TP", "FN")
N <- c("TN", "FP")

data <- tibble(
  sample = 1:100, 
  truth = sample(0:1, 100, TRUE),
  algo_a = if_else(truth == 0, sample(N, 100, TRUE), sample(P, 100, TRUE)),
  algo_b = if_else(truth == 0, sample(N, 100, TRUE), sample(P, 100, TRUE))
) %>% 
  select(sample, algo_a, algo_b)

data %>% 
  filter(algo_a %in% N) %>% # controls only: same as `algo_b %in% N` or `truth == 0`
  count(algo_a, algo_b) %>% 
  pull(n) %>%
  matrix(nrow = 2) %>% 
  mcnemar.test()
#> 
#>  McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  .
#> McNemar's chi-squared = 2.7222, df = 1, p-value = 0.09896

Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0

Can you help with this issue I'm having? I ran through line-by-line and my matrix looks a bit off. Here's the output before matrix:
1 FN                     FN                    5
2 FN                     TP                     10
3 TP                     TP                   552
4 TP                     FN                     3
This would lead me to think there is -no- difference between the two groups I'm testing. However my matrix looks like this:
[,1] [,2]
[1,]   12  383
[2,]    4    0
and shows there is a statistical difference: p-value < 2.2e-16

Not sure. The matrix should contain the same numbers as pulled from the count. Perhaps a pull() function is getting called from another package you have loaded. You could try changing to dplyr::pull() or breaking the piping up and doing matrix(c(5, 10, 552, 3), nrow = 2) %>% mcnemar.test().
